# if $||A|| \leq ||A + tB|| \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$, then A is perpendicular to B

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let A, B be non-zero vectors. Show that if $||A|| \leq ||A + tB|| \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$, then A is perpendicular to B

Answer (score 1):

From
\begin{equation}
\Vert A \Vert^2\leq \Vert A+tB \Vert^2=\Vert A\Vert^2+2t\langle A, B\rangle +t^2 \Vert B\Vert^2
\end{equation}
it follows that $\langle A,B\rangle=0$ because otherwise the RHS is smaller for small positive or small negative (depending on the sign of $\langle A,B\rangle$) values of $t$.